# mysql batch mode using a binary file

Tags: mysql, database, batch-file

I was just wondering if we can execute a binary file in batch mode. I know that a text file can be executed in batch mode using `mysql < batch-file`.

One possible motivation for such a feature can be if you are creating a `sql` file from a program then you might want to do read/write in binary mode as it is fast. Does there exist any such way in `mysql`,  I am just curious!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try using the `--hex-blob` option of `mysqldump` to create dump files that are purely text. Typically you'll do this:

```
mysqldump --hex-blob ... | gzip -9 > backup.sql.gz
```

Later you'll restore:

```
gunzip -dc backup.sql.gz | mysql ...
```

In both cases `...` represents the command-line options required to connect to your database.

This is not the most efficient way to load in large databases, but it works well enough in practice.

Answer (score 2):

mysql generates binary logs, used normally for replication.  You could generate a fake replication log and convince mysql to load it, although that's pretty hacky.  Normally replication logs are loaded into mysql using mysqlbinlog:

```
mysqlbinlog replication_log | mysql
```

Which converts the binary replication log to a text file before executing it.

Note that executing the sql is almost certainly a lot slower than parsing it, and especially so with respect to generating it.  So you're almost certainly optimizing the wrong thing.

Comment: yes i know that it will not help in optimization, but I was just thinking if its there or not, anyways thanks for the answer. I will try it out.